# Dagger 2 in Kotlin : Is there a way to do injection for class with default parameterized constructor without using Module?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I want to have my Dagger 2 inject the below class and doesn't plan to use `@Module` to do so.

So I put `@Inejct constructor` as below

```
class InjectClass @Inject constructor(var txt: String = "Default")
```

It doesn't work as it complaints

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found multiple 
@Inject constructors: [InjectClass(java.lang.String), InjectClass()]
```

Is there a way to make it work here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using a default value, you could write a secondary constructor instead:

```
class InjectClass @Inject constructor(var txt: String) {
    constructor(): this("Default")
}
```

Like this you make sure that the default constructor is not annotated with `@Inject` and *Dagger* knows how to create `InjectClass`.

Optionally, we could do this

```
class InjectClass(var txt: String) {
    @Inject constructor(): this("Default")
}
```

Comment: "Like this you make sure that the default constructor is not annotated with @Inject"

Care to explain a bit? :)

Comment: the main constructor is not annotated, as we don't want to inject this one, but the secondary constructor